# NGINX not serving django static files after ssl certificate was installed

Tags: django, nginx, certbot

After building my django app, I got it to work over http. The issue started after installing ssl certificate using certbot. Now, static files are no longer being served.

This is my nginx configuration

```
server {
   server_name pythonyard.com www.pythonyard.com *.pythonyard.com;

   location /static/ {
      alias /home/kenechukwu_webapp/allpython/backend/;
   }

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
   }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pythonyard.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pythonyard.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.pythonyard.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = pythonyard.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   listen 80;
   server_name pythonyard.com www.pythonyard.com *.pythonyard.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

I have read through lots of similar problems here on stackoverflow but none has worked for me. Please what could be wrong? This is my first time using it

Comment: Have you tried rolling it back? Meaning you comment out the second server block and the listener 443 with all the ssl configuration and add a listen 80 line in the first block? So you can try accessing it on port 80/http and have a look if it's working? Or you open the dev tools inside your browser and have a look at the network - which address is requested and then check why its not served there.

Comment: You're right, I just commented out all the ssl configuration and can now see that the static file fails. In the devtool, it returns 404

Comment: So you now access the site with http and it's still not working, right? Can you give one uri that it tries to request? Could you also provide the folder structure inside `/home/kenechukwu_webapp/allpython/backend/`?

Comment: I have solved it. I updated the file path and now everything works. Thanks alot! Do you want to add it as an answer so that I can upvote?

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity. I'll write it in a shorthand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to debug this is opening the dev tools inside your browser and have a look at the network - which address is requested and then check why it's not served there.